# how to restrict textbox for series like 1111111,2222222,3333333 etc in angularjs without for loop?

Tags: angularjs

```
<label for="licenseNumber" class="control-label">License Number: {{creditCheckController.cre}}</label>

 <input type="text" name="licenseNumber" class="form-control" id="licenseNumber" placeholder="Enter License Number" ng-model="creditEditController.creditInfo.driversLicenseNumber"
 onkeypress='return (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode >= 47 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.charCode==47) || (event.charCode==45)'  maxlength="11">
```

License number is the field which i want to restrict

Comment: Please give explicit examples which patterns are allowed and which are not.

Comment: Why "without for loop"? Whatever you use for looping it is likely implemented internally with a loop anyway.

Comment: Generate own collection of this series and pass value to check it exists in your collection.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner pattterns like 11111111,2222222,3333333upto 9999999

Comment: So, only allow a total of 7 numbers, where each number has to be the same? `1111112` would be invalid?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner same numbers are not allowed.1111112 is valid one

Comment: Then, again, provide more details. Your desired pattern is NOT clear so far.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov It also contain characters

Comment: @PhilippMeissner ..this field  does not allow user to add field like 1111111,2222222,3333333,4444444,5555555,6666666,7777777,8888888,9999999..  this all are invalid fields. Your field in last comment is valid  1111112